# Software fail to launch after re-install the OS

Tags: 18.04, apt, pulseaudio

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 without formatting and use the same username and password as the old one.

With that, most software is removed as I expect.

The problem is, after I install [pulseeffects](https://github.com/wwmm/pulseeffects) with the official command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mikhailnov/pulseeffects -y
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pulseeffects pulseaudio --install-recommends
```

The software fail to launch. Nothing happens when I use the shortcut.

Launch from command gives me this

```
(pulseeffects:32519): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 13:56:03.281: pulse_manager: Pulseaudio 11.1 does not support norewinds. Loading the sink the old way. Changing apps volume will cause cracklings

(pulseeffects:32519): pulseeffects-CRITICAL **: 13:56:03.281: pulse_manager: failed to load module-null-sink with argument: sink_name=PulseEffects_apps sink_properties=device.description="PulseEffects(apps)"device.class="sound" channels=2 rate=48000

(pulseeffects:32519): pulseeffects-WARNING **: 13:56:03.282: pulse_manager: Pulseaudio 11.1 does not support norewinds. Loading the sink the old way. Changing apps volume will cause cracklings

(pulseeffects:32519): pulseeffects-CRITICAL **: 13:56:03.282: pulse_manager: failed to load module-null-sink with argument: sink_name=PulseEffects_mic sink_properties=device.description="PulseEffects(mic)"device.class="sound" channels=2 rate=48000
[1]    32519 segmentation fault (core dumped)  pulseeffects
```

Comment: If you installed over the existing installation without formatting, know that any files that were not replaced with new files still exist.  That means it's likely that there are "leftovers" like configuration files that don't play nice with the new part of your system.  For this reason, I find it quite fruitless to reinstall this way.  If you're going to go through the effort to reinstall, may as well make it a "clean" one

Comment: Formatting is impossible unfortunately and I reinstalled it almost 3 months ago and never got any problem until this.

Comment: You might consider uninstalling the package with `sudo apt purge packagename`. `purge` is supposed to remove all configs along with the software. Then install it back and see if the error is resolved.